# Installing version 11 PIA on a Visual Studio 2008 / Office 2007 system?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, office-2007, office-2003, primary-interop-assembly

The client has development systems with Office 2007 (version 12) and Visual Studio 2008.

However, the software needs to run on Office 2003 (version 11) systems too.

How do I install the correct Primary Interop Assemblies on the development system?

I tried the ones from [Office 2003 Update: Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3c9a983a-ac14-4125-8ba0-d36d67e0f4ad&DisplayLang=en), but after installing, there is no version 11 of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` assembly on the system.

What am I missing?

--jeroen

Comment: The link says that .NET Framework 1.1 is also required, did you install that?

Comment: @Hans: yes, I did. There is no `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` version 11 on my system. @Chuck: yes, I did; `C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages1_v1.1.4322` is present and I can run .net 1.1 programs.